# What does ~$ stand for?

Tags: command-line, home-directory

What does `~$` stand for? For example:

```
user@ubuntu:~$
```

So far I know that the `$` sign is a symbol for a regular user. If I'm not mistaken `root` have `#` at the end.

I also found a lot of commands in the forums that begin with `$`:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

So for what does `$` actually stand for?

EDIT (28.01.2014) :

Today I came across this video that totally answers my question from 8 months ago and decided to share it here :)

BASH Basics - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x73WTEltyHU

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `~` and `$` are elements of the *command line prompt*. This indicates that your computer (or more exactly, I guess, the shell you are running) is waiting for user input.  It is *prompting* you to input a command.

The `$` is merely a separator or divider. It separates the command prompt from the command which follows it.  When people write such things as `$ sudo apt-get update` (your example), they are simply telling you that the command, in this case `sudo apt-get update`, needs to be entered at a command prompt. Strictly speaking, perhaps, the `$` is redundant in this context.

Other separators may be used in other situations. For example, `#` is used for a root shell.

The `~` (called 'tilde') is shorthand for your home directory.  When it appears in a command prompt, e.g., `user@hostame:~$`, it indicates that the current *working directory* is your home directory.  Thus if you run the list command, `ls`, without specifying any particular directory, it will list the contents of your home directory.

(By the way, `$HOME`, is not a command, as you suggest, but rather an *environment variable*. It determines the location of your home directory.  You can see its value by running `$ echo $HOME`.)

Comment: @FEarBG I think this answer fails in one small aspect: the prompt is completely customizable and is just a decoration; you could decide to have an empty prompt, or use whatever symbols you like in it(e.g. on my computer I have replaced `$` with ` ̃∴` as prompt symbol). You can change your prompt setting the `PS1` environment variable to your liking.

Comment: @Bakuriu Assuming bash, of course. Other shells MAY be different.

Comment: "Strictly speaking, perhaps, the $ is redundant in this context." - Yes, that is why we generally prefer to avoid the `$` if there's no need for it (which there is for log copies or example outputs, for instance).

Answer (score 12):

Traditionally, a shell prompt either ends with $, % or #. If it ends with $, this indicates a shell that's compatible with the Bourne shell (such as a POSIX shell, or a Korn shell, or Bash). If it ends with %, this indicates a C shell (csh or tcsh). If it ends with #, this indicates that the shell is running as the system's superuser account (root).

**Source**: [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1852263&p=11297940#post11297940)

Comment: on some (old, usually) systems, you have "#" even as a regular user (maybe to keep you on your toe ^^)... ie, some older shells don't change the symbol if you're root -vs- regular user.

Comment: [Other possible source](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide#line-63)

Answer (score 10):

- `~` stands for your home directory.
- `$` it's a separator for your system, it comes from the command `\$` from the [man page.](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html)

So if you find a command beginning with `$` it just says that nothing should be added before that.

```
user@ubuntu:~$
```

`user` is the username your are logged in with. 
`@` is just to say here is a link.
`ubuntu` is the name of the system you are logged in as. 
`:~` says that you are in the `user` home directory now.
`$` comes from the `\$` escape sequence in the `$PS1`. [man page.](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html)

But this can all be changed by reading in the [man page.](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html) 
Thank you @demure for the help.

Comment: To be specific, it is the `\$` portion of the $PS1, which is designed to show `$` if not root (otherwise it will be `#`) [man page exert](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html)

Comment: @denure updated my answer, if you feel you can improve it please do so.

Answer (score 6):

The $ sign it the end of the prompt in terminal when you add a command like the one you showed, do not type in the $ else it will not work.

So **$ sudo apt-get update**

would be typed in as:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Hope that helps.

## Edit

The ~ stands for your Home folder so `name@pc_name:~/Desktop$` would show that you are in the Home>Desktop folder.

Comment: Perhaps to show that you should enter the command at the prompt.

Comment: And also to distinguish between a command run by a normal user (at the $ prompt) vs. root (the # prompt).

Comment: @FEarBG: It's an arbitrary convention, unrelated (as far as I know) to the use of `$` to denote a variable name. There are only so many printable characters available on a keyboard. DOS and Windows use `>` in prompts, Unix usually uses `$` or `%`. It tells you "this is a prompt" without wasting space on your screen (or, in the old days, ink and paper).

Comment: And of course, in DOS and Windows environment variables use `%`. As you say, it's largely arbitrary; there pretty much needs to be *something*, but it doesn't need to be the same everywhere (although it would be kind of nice if it was).